# Making an HTML Jigsaw Puzzle in Flash CC

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, action

I am working on a jigsaw puzzle game for a media arts class. I have followed a tutorial and redone it 3-4 times and I still can't interact with the tiles.

**This is the Action Script 3 code**

```
//*********************
// Initialize:

var numPieces = 16;

for (var i = 0; i < numPieces; i++)
{
    var pieceName = "p" + (i + 1);
    var piece = this[pieceName];
    if( piece ){
        piece.name = pieceName;
        piece.on("mousedown", function(evt) 
        {
            this.scaleX = 1;
            this.scaleY = 1;
            this.shadow = null;
            this.parent.addChild(this);// Bump to top
            this.offset = {x:this.x - evt.stageX, y:this.y - evt.stageY};
        });
        piece.on("pressmove", function(evt) 
        {
            this.x = evt.stageX + this.offset.x;
            this.y = evt.stageY + this.offset.y;
        });
        piece.on("pressup", function(evt) 
        {
            var target = this.parent["t"+this.name.substr(1)];
            if( target && hitTestInRange( target, 30) ){
                this.x = target.x;
                this.y = target.y;
            }
        });
    }
}

function hitTestInRange( target, range )
{
    if( target.x > stage.mouseX - range &&
        target.x < stage.mouseX + range &&
        target.y > stage.mouseY - range &&
        target.y < stage.mouseY + range )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**The same code in Java Script**

It was to many characters so here it is on pastebin
http://pastebin.com/v9M2nSPd

**If it would be helpful I can also post the flash file and the HTML file**

I am hoping that someone here can help me figure out why I am unable to interact with any of my puzzle pieces.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @xxbbcc Sorry i''l edit the post.

Comment: That looks like jquery: `piece.on("mousedown",function`.  In AS3 you need to do: `piece.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function)`.  To see the list of various AS3 mouse events, look here:   http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#constantSummary

Comment: @Batman I tried changing each instance of piece.on("mousedown",function to piece.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_X, function) and It's now just a grey screen any idea on what's causing this

Comment: `MouseEvent.MOUSE_X` doesn't exist.   Use `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN` and make sure you're importing `flash.events.MouseEvent` at the top of your page

Comment: @Batman Yeah, I meant x as a placeholder so x=UP x=DOWN etc I'll try importing mouse events though thanks

Do you mind taking a look at my current code and seeing if you can see any huge issues? http://pastebin.com/2je1uXPb